# Phoenix unit test how to check if connection object is redirected to particular path?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

Let's say I have a controller action `some_action/2` which redirects to `/a-path`. I need to write a unit test which asserts if the connection is redirected to `/a-path`. How to do that in Pheonix.

Answer (score 2):

Use `redirected_to` function to assert if the connection is redirected to a particular path, as the following example.

```
   test "redirects to the path /a-path", %{conn: conn, user: user} do
      new_conn = some_action(conn, %{})
      assert redirected_to(new_conn) == "/a-path"
    end
```